# How to send files to another app on ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, dropbox

Dropbox application permit to send files to other applications like teamviewer or iBook. How do they do that?

I thought the only way to send data to another application was the url scheme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Dropbox using [Document Interaction](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010403) API to provide this functionality.

Quotes from [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PreviewingandOpeningItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010410-SW1):

You can use a document interaction controller to display a file preview or to prompt the user to choose an action for a file.

- To modally display a file preview, call the `presentPreviewAnimated:` method.
- To prompt the user with a set of options, including an option to open the file in another app, call the `presentOptionsMenuFromRect:inView:animated:` or `presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem:animated:` method.
- To prompt the user only to open the file in another app, call the `presentOpenInMenuFromRect:inView:animated`: or `presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:animated:` method.

Answer (score 2):

[`UIDocumentInteractionController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PreviewingandOpeningItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010410-SW1) gives the user the option to open a file using other applications.