# iOS URL Scheme Microsoft Outlook App

Tags: ios, outlook, url-scheme

This seems impossible to find, unless perhaps there isn't one for it.  But anyone know (if there is one) the iOS URL Scheme for opening the Microsoft Outlook Mobile App right to the Compose Screen with pre-defined TO_EMAIL, SUBJECT and BODY?

Answer (score 22):

Here is a link I found that helped me out with the [IOS Outlook URL Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369198/i-just-want-to-open-ms-outlook-app-and-see-mailto-screen-using-url-scheme-at-ios).

From that I was able to come up with this code:

```
// Create an array of recipients for the email.
NSArray* emailRecipients = @[@"example@email.com", @"example2@email.com"];

// Create a mutable string to hold all of the recipient email addresses and add the first one.
NSMutableString* emailTo = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:emailRecipients[0]];
// Loop through all of the email recipients except for the first one.
for (int index = 1; index < emailRecipients.count; index++)
{
    // Add a semicolon and then the email address at the current index.
    [emailTo appendFormat:@";%@", emailRecipients[index]];
}

// Get the email subject from the subject text field.
NSString* emailSubject = fieldSubject.text;
// Encode the string for URL.
NSString* encodedSubject = [emailSubject stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
// Get the email body from the body text field.
NSString* emailBody = fieldBody.text;
// Encode the string for URL.
NSString* encodedBody = [emailBody stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];

// See if the subject or body are empty.
if (![emailSubject length] || ![emailBody length])
{
    // Exit.
    return;
}

// Create a string with the URL scheme and email properties.
NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ms-outlook://compose?to=%@&subject=%@&body=%@", emailTo, encodedSubject, encodedBody];
// Convert the string to a URL.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
// Open the app that responds to the URL scheme (should be Outlook).
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

The URL scheme for Outlook is: ms-outlook://compose?to=example@email.com&subject=Subject&body=Message

Hope this helps!

Comment: I found your answer really helpful. The only thing missing in this is about the attachment. Can you help?

Comment: @Moh Any luck with attachment?

Comment: I cannot say for certain, but I do not believe this is possible with URL scheme. You might look into Document Interaction see the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876648/how-to-send-files-to-another-app-on-ios.

Comment: This appears to be broken with Outlook for iOS version 4.14.x and up (4.15.0 as of this posting). The encoded HTML has all of it's tag delimiters stripped, so <br><p> becomes brp. I've tried a few of the other URL allowed character set encodings, but with no success. I'm thinking they no longer allow HTML passed in through that Body parameter but can't find official documentation. Any ideas?

Comment: @jhelzer any updates on this issue ? we are facing the same bug.

Comment: @Mosbah So I created https://stackoverflow.com/q/59257114, last I heard is that Microsoft is not bringing this back for security reasons. We have moved to change all our Outlook sharing to as plain a text email as possible, URL shorteners when connected to the internet and removing all formatting.

Answer (score 4):

## Swift

```
func outlookDeepLink(subject: String, body: String, recipients: [String]) throws -> URL {
    
    enum MailComposeError: Error {
        case emptySubject
        case emptyBody
        case unexpectedError
    }
    
    guard !subject.isEmpty else { throw MailComposeError.emptySubject }
    guard !body.isEmpty else { throw MailComposeError.emptyBody }
    
    let emailTo = recipients.joined(separator: ";")
    
    var components = URLComponents()
    components.scheme = "ms-outlook"
    components.host = "compose"
    components.queryItems = [
        URLQueryItem(name: "to", value: emailTo),
        URLQueryItem(name: "subject", value: subject),
        URLQueryItem(name: "body", value: body),
    ]
    
    guard let deepURL = components.url else { throw MailComposeError.unexpectedError }
    return deepURL
}
```

#### Usage

```
try! UIApplication.shared.open(
    outlookDeepLink(
        subject: "subject",
        body: "body",
        recipients: ["example@email.com", "example2@email.com"]
    )
)
```

#### Note that:

1. Don't forget to tell iOS you are going to call `ms-outlook`. (Add it to `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in `info.plist`, Otherwise, You will get an clear error message in console if you forget it)
2. Also don't forget to check if the app actually exists before trying to open the url. (`canOpenURL` is here to help)