# Programmatically add calendar event to Outlook on iOS or Android

Tags: android, ios, outlook, calendar, icalendar

I have a client requesting that our mobile application add a feature to add a calendar event to the Outlook app on iOS/Android. We already provide addition of calendar events via the native APIs on each platform, but they have specifically indicated that their security policies do not allow the user to sync their Exchange accounts via the built-in calendar sync and it needs to be added directly through the Outlook app. I have indicated that it may not be possible if no API or URL scheme exists to do so, but they are adamant.

Ideally, I would like to be able to pass in a .ics file to the Outlook app, but I'm thinking that's a very long shot.

I also found the following post: [iOS URL Scheme Microsoft Outlook App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190891/ios-url-scheme-microsoft-outlook-app?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) which addresses how to compose an email address via URL scheme. I am unable to find any additional documentation on the `ms-outlook://` URL scheme because there are too many search results which match anything with the phrase "Outlook" in it.

If there is any documentation for `ms-outlook://` or passing an .ics file to Outlook to create a calendar event, it would be much appreciated.

Edit: As a proof of concept, I've also tried emailing an .ics to the Outlook app and then opening it there... No luck. Also tried opening an .ics file in Outlook via the iOS Share Sheet and it attaches the file as an attachment in a compose window rather than giving you the option to save it to your calendar.

Comment: So this: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/android-java-snippets-sample doesn't apply to your problem?

Comment: I’m not familiar with the Microsoft Graph, they tend to drop that term often without explanation. I’ll look this over tomorrow and see if it applies to my case but my suspicion is that this requires authentication, which is far beyond the scope of work and complexity we want to add to the application. A simple .ics import or creation by URL scheme w/o regard to authentication is what is needed. I suspect it doesn’t exist.

Comment: Based on the comments on this thread: https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/293346-outlook-for-android/suggestions/9623127-support-for-ics-calendar-files?page=1&per_page=20 I would agree that it isn't supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this out: (iOS)

`ms-outlook://events/new?title=MY%20MEETING&start=2019-01-29T13:00:00&end=2019-01-29T14:00:00&location=LOCATION&attendees=some.person@email.com`

For Android, replace `ms-outlook://` with `msoutlook://`.

EDIT: The iOS header seems to work on Android as well.

Comment: Nothing official, I don’t think.

Comment: How can i use this can you please tell me. i want to add same thing.
I added question in SO. can you please help me ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60527754/add-event-in-outlook-calendar-swift-5
Thanks!