# Outlook for iOS removing Spaces with ms-outlook://compose

Tags: ios, outlook

We have an iOS app that generates an Outlook email using ms-outlook://compose.  Previously, this worked correctly and we could include spaces in the output using %20. Even HTML was working correctly.

But recently we noticed that Outlook is removing all of the spaces from the content we are sending over. There have been recent updates to the Outlook iOS app that are likely the cause.

Has anyone seen this behavior and are aware of any work arounds?

Comment: It seems to be a problem from Outlook 4.14.x Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59257114/how-to-configure-html-body-for-ms-outlook-compose-body-parameter-for-outlook-f).